# Output column on unpivoted row(s) with hardcoded value specific to that row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have the below query that uses `unpivot` to output values in `FREIGHT_AMT` and/or `SALETX_AMT` into the `MERCHANDISE_AMT` column so that I can output these as separate invoice lines.

What I need to do for any unpivoted rows I output (`FREIGHT_AMT`, `SALETAX_AMT`) is output the string 'FREIGHT' (for `FREIGHT_AMT` rows) and 'TAX' (for `SALETX_AMT`) rows in the column `Line_Type`.

Normally I would think of doing this in a `CASE` statement in the original query, however because at this point those are still columns and not rows I'm not sure how I can correctly indicate this.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM PS_DISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                             
          THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END AS LineType, A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, C.FREIGHT_AMT
          , C.SALETX_AMT

FROM  PS_VOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_DISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_VOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PS_PYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

WHERE 
C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
AND A.VOUCHER_ID IN ('00720667', '00721196', '00721021', '00721171', '00326705'))

SELECT INVOICE_ID,  VOUCHER_LINE_NUM - 1 + row_number() over 
(PARTITION BY INVOICE_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM ORDER BY VOUCHER_LINE_NUM) AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,LineType ,Value
FROM CTE
unpivot (Value FOR col IN (MERCHANDISE_AMT, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT)) u
WHERE Value <> 0.00
```

**Desired Output from unpivoted query:**

```
INVOICE_ID       VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    LineType        Value
1100000720667    1                   ITEM            17480.820
1100000720667    2                   FREIGHT         59.500
1100000721196    5                   ITEM            4680.200
1100000721196    6                   FREIGHT         55.500
1100000721196    7                   TAX             512.890
```

**EDIT: This includes sample data of my current data:**

```
--CREATE TABLES:

CREATE TABLE #TempVOUCHER_LINE (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), VOUCHER_LINE_NUM varchar (4), MERCHANDISE_AMT decimal (7,3))

CREATE TABLE #TempDISTRIB_LINE (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), VOUCHER_LINE_NUM varchar (4))
   
CREATE TABLE #TempVOUCHER (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), FREIGHT_AMT decimal (7,3), SALETX_AMT decimal (7,3), INVOICE_DT datetime, ACCOUNTING_DT datetime, CLOSE_STATUS varchar(4) )

CREATE TABLE #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), PYMNT_ID varchar (10))

--INSERT DATA INTO TEMP TABLES:

INSERT INTO #TempVOUCHER_LINE 
 (BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, MERCHANDISE_AMT)
 VALUES ('11000', '00720667', '1', 1748.820),
        ('11000', '00721196', '5', 4680.200)

INSERT INTO #TempDISTRIB_LINE
 (BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)
 VALUES ('11000', '00720667', '1'),
        ('11000', '00721196', '5')              

INSERT INTO #TempVOUCHER
(BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT, INVOICE_DT, ACCOUNTING_DT, CLOSE_STATUS)
VALUES ('11000', '00720667', 59.50, 0.00, '2019-05-03', '2014-05-14', 'A'),
       ('11000', '00721196', 55.50, 512.890, '2020-08-10', '2020-08-12', 'A')

INSERT INTO #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF
(BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, PYMNT_ID)
VALUES ('11000', '00720667', ''),
       ('11000', '00721196', '')

--QUERY FROM TEMP TABLES:
;
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT,A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID, A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #TempDISTRIB_LINE 
                  WHERE BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                    AND VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                    AND VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)                                                                             
          THEN 'ITEM' ELSE 'MISCELLANEOUS' END AS LineType, A.MERCHANDISE_AMT, C.FREIGHT_AMT
          , C.SALETX_AMT

FROM  #TempVOUCHER_LINE A
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempDISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempVOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID

WHERE 
C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'    
AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
AND A.VOUCHER_ID IN ('00720667', '00721196', '00721021', '00721171', '00326705'))

SELECT INVOICE_ID,  VOUCHER_LINE_NUM - 1 + row_number() over (PARTITION BY INVOICE_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM ORDER BY VOUCHER_LINE_NUM) AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, LineType   --CASE WHEN FREIGHT_AMT <> 0.00 THEN 'FREIGHT' WHEN SALETX_AMT <> 0.00 THEN 'TAX' ELSE 'ITEM' END AS LineType 
,Value
FROM CTE
unpivot (Value FOR col IN (MERCHANDISE_AMT, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT)) u
WHERE Value <> 0.00
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
INVOICE_ID      VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    LineType    Value
1100000720667   1                   ITEM        1748.820
1100000720667   2                   ITEM        59.500
1100000721196   5                   ITEM        4680.200
1100000721196   6                   ITEM        55.500
1100000721196   7                   ITEM        512.890
```

**DESIRED OUTPUT:**

```
INVOICE_ID      VOUCHER_LINE_NUM    LineType    Value
1100000720667   1                   ITEM        1748.820
1100000720667   2                   FREIGHT     59.500
1100000721196   5                   ITEM        4680.200
1100000721196   6                   FREIGHT     55.500
1100000721196   7                   TAX         512.890
```

Duplication error (based on Larnu's answer:)

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE #TempVOUCHER_LINE (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), VOUCHER_LINE_NUM varchar (4), MERCHANDISE_AMT decimal (8,3))

--DROP TABLE #TempDISTRIB_LINE
CREATE TABLE #TempDISTRIB_LINE (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), VOUCHER_LINE_NUM varchar (4))

--DROP TABLE #TempVOUCHER

CREATE TABLE #TempVOUCHER (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), FREIGHT_AMT decimal (7,3), SALETX_AMT decimal (7,3), INVOICE_DT datetime, ACCOUNTING_DT datetime, CLOSE_STATUS varchar(4) )

--DROP TABLE #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF
CREATE TABLE #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF (BUSINESS_UNIT varchar(10), VOUCHER_ID varchar(16), PYMNT_ID varchar (10))

--DROP TABLE #TempVOUCHER_LINE

INSERT INTO #TempVOUCHER_LINE 
 (BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM, MERCHANDISE_AMT)
 VALUES ('11000', '00720667', '1', 17480.820),
        ('11000', '00721196', '5', 4680.200),
        ('11000', '00721021', '1', 82.64),
        ('11000', '00721021', '2', 542.12),
        ('11000', '00721021', '3', 126.89),
        ('11000', '00721021', '4', 1022.03)

--DROP TABLE #TempDISTRIB_LINE
INSERT INTO #TempDISTRIB_LINE
 (BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM)
 VALUES ('11000', '00720667', '1'),
        ('11000', '00721196', '5'),
        ('11000', '00721021', '1'),
        ('11000', '00721021', '2'),
        ('11000', '00721021', '3'),
        ('11000', '00721021', '4')

        --SELECT * FROM #TempVOUCHER
--DROP TABLE #TempVOUCHER
INSERT INTO #TempVOUCHER
(BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, FREIGHT_AMT, SALETX_AMT, INVOICE_DT, ACCOUNTING_DT, CLOSE_STATUS)
VALUES ('11000', '00720667', 59.50, 0.00, '05-03-2019', '05-14-2014', 'A'),
       ('11000', '00721196', 55.50, 512.890, '08-10-2020', '08-12-2020', 'A'),
       ('11000', '00721021', 129.01, 0.00, '12-13-2019', '12-16-2019', 'A')

--DROP TABLE #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF
INSERT INTO #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF
(BUSINESS_UNIT, VOUCHER_ID, PYMNT_ID)
VALUES ('11000', '00720667', ''),
       ('11000', '00721196', ''),
       ('11000', '00721021', '')

;

--SQL QUERY:

WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID,
            A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
            A.MERCHANDISE_AMT,
            C.FREIGHT_AMT,
            C.SALETX_AMT
     FROM #TempVOUCHER_LINE A
          LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempDISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                             AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                                             AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
          LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempVOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                        AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                                AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
     WHERE C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
       AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
       AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
       AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
       AND A.VOUCHER_ID IN ('00720667', '00721196', '00721021', '00721171', '00326705'))
SELECT C.INVOICE_ID,
       C.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.INVOICE_ID, VOUCHER_LINE_NUM ORDER BY VOUCHER_LINE_NUM) - 1 AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
       V.LineType,
       V.[Value]
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Merchandise',C.MERCHANDISE_AMT),
                        ('Freight',C.FREIGHT_AMT),
                        ('Tax',C.SALETX_AMT))V(LineType, Value)
WHERE V.[Value] <> 0;
```

Comment: Put the `CASE` **expression** (`CASE` is not a statement in T-SQL) in the outer `SELECT`, not the inner one?

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean? I'm not sure how to output the unpivoted rows to be either 'FREIGHT' or 'TAX'.

Comment: Your statement *"Normally I would think of doing this in a CASE statement in the original query"* Implied you understand how to use a `CASE` expression, @Nick , so you just need to put the `CASE` in the right place.

Comment: Is the `CASE` statement in the final Select executing **after** the `unpivot` occurs? As that would be the only way I can see a `CASE` statement working...

Comment: You can't use `Case` (`Switch`) statements in T-SQL; as I mentioned. T-SQL only supports `CASE` **expressions**.

Comment: Thats what I meant. It would be helpful if you could show me what you're referring to that you think would solve this.

Comment: Put the `CASE` expression in the part of the query where the values exist. I can't run your query but I *assume* that's in the outer `SELECT`, rather than the inner `SELECT` (the subquery).

Comment: Every `INVOICE_ID` will have a row with an 'ITEM' `LineType`, and then depending on if that `INVOICE_ID` has a `FREIGHT_AMT` value greater than 0.00 and/or` SALETX_AMT` column has an amount greater than 0.00 then in the unpivoted rows that are output I need to assign the value of 'FREIGHT' and 'TAX', respectfully to properly identify those as such.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235060/discussion-between-nick-and-larnu).

Comment: We need sample data, in a consumable format, and expected results here. If a `CASE` isn't working as well, include your attempt to try implement it and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: I have added CREATE/INSERT scripts with my sample data above.

Comment: Thanks. Do, however, check that your scripts are valid when posting. You don't terminate your statements, so you get an error at the `WITH`, and there aren't 14 months in a year (When supplying date literal make sure they are language agnostic).

Comment: I believe I have made the appropriate modifications above.

Comment: `'2014-05-14'` isn't a valid `datetime` for anyone outside of America, I'm afraid. I've made the needed amendments in my own environment though.

Comment: Sorry it was working fine for me. Thanks for adjusting accordingly and looking at this...

Comment: So, in your attempt, where are the values `'FREIGHT'` and `'TAX'` coming from? The only values your column `LineType` is defined to be able to have is `'ITEM'` and `'MISCELLANEOUS'`.

Comment: I didn't know how to do that because before unpivoting the values come from the same row as the 'ITEM' INVOICE_ID would be on. I need to still have the `CASE` statement evaluating for the `ITEM` and `MISCELLANEOUS` line types as shown in the example desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this is what you want. I prefer to not use the restrictive `UNPIVOT` operator, and instead use a `VALUES` table construct. Note you'll need to replace `{Some Expression}` will an expression that defines the order of your row numbering:

```sql
WITH CTE AS
    (SELECT CONCAT(A.BUSINESS_UNIT, A.VOUCHER_ID) AS INVOICE_ID,
            A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
            A.MERCHANDISE_AMT,
            C.FREIGHT_AMT,
            C.SALETX_AMT
     FROM #TempVOUCHER_LINE A
          LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempDISTRIB_LINE B ON B.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                             AND B.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
                                             AND B.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM = A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
          LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempVOUCHER C ON C.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                        AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
          LEFT OUTER JOIN #TempPYMNT_VCHR_XREF I ON I.BUSINESS_UNIT = A.BUSINESS_UNIT
                                                AND I.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
     WHERE C.INVOICE_DT > '01-03-2019'
       AND C.ACCOUNTING_DT < '06-01-2021'
       AND I.PYMNT_ID = ''
       AND C.CLOSE_STATUS <> 'C'
       AND A.VOUCHER_ID IN ('00720667', '00721196', '00721021', '00721171', '00326705'))
SELECT C.INVOICE_ID,
       C.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY C.INVOICE_ID ORDER BY {Some Expression}) - 1 AS VOUCHER_LINE_NUM,
       V.LineType,
       V.[Value]
FROM CTE C
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Merchandise',C.MERCHANDISE_AMT),
                        ('Freight',C.FREIGHT_AMT),
                        ('Tax',C.SALETX_AMT))V(LineType, Value)
WHERE V.[Value] <> 0;
```

Comment: I am seeing an issue for INVOICE_ID's that have multiple VOUCHER_LINE_NUM on them. The 'TAX' / 'FREIGHT' rows are getting duplicated for each VOUCHER_LINE_NUM on them. I provided a screenshot above of the issue. The 'TAX' / 'FREIGHT' rows should only be applied once per INVOICE_ID, not on each INVOICE_ID+VOUCHER_LINE_NUM. I have provided a screenshot above of the duplication.

Comment: I don't have this problem for the sample data you provided, @Nick : [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9bf8f083921fa35da93213ee9419e314). perhaps you've changed something?

Comment: I updated the post above (EDIT 2) with additional sample data. You can see for INVOICE_ID 1100000721021 I am getting duplicate 'Freight' rows for each VOUCHER_LINE_NUM. I am PARTITIONED by C.INVOICE_ID and C.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM and ORDERED BY VOUCHER_LINE_NUM. Even with playing with this I still see the duplication occuring.

Comment: Ordering and partitioning on the same column doesn't make a lot of sense @Nick . What goes first out of the following values, for example? 1, 1, 1, or 1? Why that specific 1?

Comment: You don't define what numbers they should be either @Nick . Unfortunately I can't guess what they should be. It seems like the row numbering is the problem now, not the unpivoting, which is a completely different question.

Comment: the 'FREIGHT' and 'TAX' unpivoted rows should be the last VOUCHER_LINE_NUM for a given INVOICE_ID. So for the last example of INVOICE_ID 1100000721021 that already has 4 rows (lines) I would expect to see the 'FREIGHT' and/or 'TAX' have VOUCHER_LINE_NUM of 5 (if either is populated) and 5 and 6 (if both are populated), respectfully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235094/discussion-between-nick-and-larnu).

Comment: @Nick you're asking a new question here; how to fix the row numbering. I've answered the question as it was originally asked. if you've moved the goal posts/have a new question you should ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks. I've accepted the answer and posted a new question with the issue I am currently facing.